# Reuse of java beans for REST acceptance tests

Tags: java, rest

We have acceptance tests for our REST endpoints using rest-assured. The tests currently have they're own fluent JSON builders. They help us remove noice from our tests. For example.

`.body(someUser().withEmail('joe@games.com').toJson()).post(...`

We could even improve that design more by creating fluent beans with Jackson-annotations.

`.body(someUser().withEmail('joe@games.com')).post(...`

It then is very tempting to reuse the beans from production which are already annotated. We could inherit those and add fluent setters.

What are the pros/cons in reusing those beans and is it considered a best practice?

---

Additionally if anyone could point me to a open source project trying to do something similar it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So basically you're saying  that you want to test beans using the same beans that you're testing?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm doing end-to-end tests so I'm not only testing the Bean.  But your point as valid tough, I would not be testing the bean if I reuse it. BTW, this is not something I want to do, I'm trying to persuade a college...